# django - FormSet: ingore forms contaning only initial values

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

I have a FormSet and each form contains one filed with initial value:

```
class IssueForm(forms.Form):

    date_of_issue = forms.DateField(
            initial=date.today().strftime("%d.%m.%Y"),
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': date.today().strftime("%d.%m.%Y"),
                'class': 'form-control',
            }),
            localize=True,
            required=True)
```

Now the user gets 10 extra forms displayed but maybe he/she just fills 5 of them. Now the field date_of_issue is required and so after submitting the formSet it'll be displayed again and marking those 5 rows not filled by the user.

I tried to add my own clean function for the field but I don't know if this is the way to go:

```
def clean_date_of_issue(self):
    if len(self.cleaned_data) == 1 and 'date_of_issue' in self.cleaned_data:
        self.cleaned_data = dict()
        return None
    return self.cleaned_data['date_of_issue']
```

Comment: What is the result from your current clean function? What's wrong with it?

Comment: @HåkenLid I get the forms displayed again and those forms with just one filled field (the date_of_issue with the initial value) are marked as "need to be filled" (as other fields of the form are required). I don't know if the clean function is the way to go ...

Comment: I see. I find that you lose a lot of the convenience of the django forms framework once you start any not trivial overriding of methods and functionality. In this case, I would consider either dropping the placeholder, or find some client side solution to this. A javascript "today" button to fill the date, maybe. Or a javascript function that pre validates formsets on submit, and filters out the sub forms where only `date_of_issue` is filled.

Comment: I haven't used formsets much, so I can't give you a suggestion to how this can be done server side. Looks like the `clean_field` method doesn't work, so it's a matter of figuring out which other method to override. I would look at the `changed_data` property and the `has_changed` method of the  [`django.forms.forms.BaseForm` class.](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.7/django/forms/forms.py#L64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx @håken-lid for pushing me into the code. I should have done it in the first place.

At the end I don't know what did the trick. I've overwritten most of the clean functions and check the errors at the levels of validation (read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/). It helps!)

One thing is the show_hidden_initial. It seems to be necessary for the form to recognize that the initial value didn't change:

```
class IssueForm(forms.Form):
    # ...

    date_of_issue = forms.DateField(
            initial=date.today().strftime("%d.%m.%Y"),
            show_hidden_initial=True,
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': date.today().strftime("%d.%m.%Y"),
                'class': 'form-control, datepicker',
            }),
            localize=True,
            required=True)
```

Another approach was to overwrite the form clean function and remove the error (not a really nice solution):

```
class IssueForm(forms.Form):
    # ...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(IssueForm, self).clean()

        # get all non default fields
        not_default_fields = [value for key, value in cleaned_data.items() if key not in ('date_of_issue', 'issuer')]

        if any(not_default_fields) is False and 'value' in self.errors:
            # remove the error if it's the only one
            self.errors.pop('value')

        return cleaned_data
```

I don't know why it didn't work like expected in the first place but now it does ...